# How to response xml with node js express?

Tags: node.js, xml, express

I want to write a function that could generate sitemap like https://www.bbc.co.uk/sitemap.xml. So here's my code

```
module.exports.sitemapTag = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const defaultPath = 'https://example.com/tag';
    const tagList = [];
    const data = { tags: await TagService.getAllTag() };
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-restricted-syntax
    for (const item of data.tags) {
      const element = {
        sitemap: {
          tag: defaultPath.concat(item.tagText),
          tagNum: item.tagNumber,
        },
      };
      tagList.push(element);
    }
    const feed = xmlbuilder.create(tagList, { encoding: 'utf-8' });
    return res.status(200).send(feed.end({ pretty: true }));
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return res.status(400).json(null);
  }
};
```

But the result when I accessed `localhost://9191/api/v1/sitemapTag` is just a string like this:

```
http://example.com/tag/Cookies 2 http://example.com/tag/Candy 1 http://example.com/tag/Chocolate 3
```

Then I tried use: `console.log(feed.end({ pretty: true }));`
to see what happened, my console log like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <sitemap>
   <tag>http://example.com/tag/Cookies</tag>
   <tagNum>2</tagNum>
 </sitemap>
 <sitemap>
   <tag>http://example.com/tag/Candy</tag>
   <tagNum>1</tagNum>
 </sitemap>
 <sitemap>
   <tag>http://example.com/tag/Chocolate</tag>
   <tagNum>3</tagNum>
 </sitemap>
```

How could I solve this correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is probably because you're using the default content type (html maybe) so all the tags are hidden because it's being intepreted as HTML

you need to set content type to to `text/xml` before

```js
res.header("Content-Type", "text/xml");
return res.status(200).send(feed.end({ pretty: true }));
```

Comment: It worked. I haven't set content type yet. Thank you so much